# Epson dot matrix printer, print on large paper size (FX-890 and LQ-590)

Tags: php, printing, dot-matrix

Short story:

I need to print to a really large paper on my work (it's like 5 pages letter united), we use a custom paper configuration but printers has a limit per page and i dont know if we can use "printing continuously" or something to achieve this. We failed on this. maybe it's configuration?

Full story:

We have a big report made with FPDF, it must fit a large paper (pre-printed forms), due to printer paper size limit, we devided the report in two pages (tried with only one page but stops printing at limit), both pages with the maximun limit of the printer and we make a custom paper size in the printer configuration.

Then it works in Epson FX-890, at the end of first page, the printer make a small jump and continue printing the second page in the same paper. It fit perfectly on the large paper.

But now, they bought a Epson LQ-590 (and others models) but in this case failed to print, because when printing, at the end of first page just stops and throw the entire large page. Does not print the second page until you put another paper, but it's only one paper!

¿What I can do?
¿There is a configuration for big large paper?
¿There is a way to just print continuously line by line, avoiding paper size?
¿There is an api, program, or something to achieve this?

We are thinking in using C# java or anyhing to try another way. Also we are considering to buy more epson fx-890 and do nothing more. But we don't know if is a fx-890 feature or just an error of the printer.

Comment: Why would you use php for printing?

Comment: The info is on a web server, php + mysql. We are printing a PDF file (with two large page size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, maybe it's not a true answer but I hope the information that I gathered can help others.

So many tries, diferent configurations, diferent drivers, diferent pc and OS, for nothing. I consulted epson support, they told me to test diferent paper size and configurations, they says "it should print continuously if the page fits on paper" and gave me tips to try a test with two half-letter pages (ms word) and one physical letter paper, and nothing, it prints only the first and wait for another paper for second, on both printer models.

They warn about the limits of the dot matrix printers, they recomend others models(lasers) that can support that kind of paper. But we need the matrix printer for the "copy", document with 3 layers.

Also I asked for a "line by line" mode or by using c# code, he asked on other department and told me this kind of printer doesnt have this mode, only really old models have this capacity. Also I searched for the code and you can set the page size but the limit it's the same.

We test with other two FX-890 and works perfectly. Even on diferent OS and diferent drivers. So we decided to buy more FX-890. Not a perfect solution but it's something.

Conclusion:

1. No, you cannot set a paper bigger than the printer limit.
2. No, there is not a configuration for "print continuously omiting
   page size"
3. No, you cannot print "line by line" with code (on these models) the
   limit it's the same and you have to define a paper.